# Problem with FireFox formatting Links with VBScript

Tags: css, asp-classic, vbscript

For all those out there that claim FireFox to be the superior browser, why can't FireFox properly format a link when a vbscript is contained in the HREF?

Example:

```
<A HREF="<% =DEF_ROOT %>Products/category.asp?ID=1" CLASS="normal_link">
```

This link will not apply the formatting specified by the class until it has been clicked on at least once, however, the hover formatting will work.  It seems as FireFox can't tell it is a link until the user actually clicks it.  This is not a problem in IE.

If anyone knows a solution, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Without actually seeing the page, I'd hazard a guess that it's because you are *still* using capitalised HTML. This was deprecated since HTML4 or so, and doesn't work with XHTML. In XHMTL `<a>` and `<A>` are two totally different tags.

Comment: @KingMaximo Go put your page through http://validator.w3.org/ then come back and edit your question if you're having issues after sorting out any validation errors. Please include more background about exactly what your code is besides just this one tag.

Comment: Changing to lower-case doesn't do anything. The code isn't important, it's just the link's CLASS formatting.  The DEF_ROOT variable is just a variable pulled from a database that contains the Path, so that every file wouldn't need to be changed even if the files were moved to another location. This is an e-commerce application with an administrator back-end that I developed years ago. I just recently tested with FireFox and noticed this weird behavior, there is not anything wrong in the code, it worked for companies for years.

Comment: @KingMaximo run the page through the validator. I'm willing to bet there's more than one error that's been laying dormant.

Comment: The validator is only showing errors for images used for layout purposes not containing an ALT tag.  This doesn't have anything to do with the CLASS not formatting, as I said if you click on the link the formatting will be applied once you return to the page.  This tells me it is a problem with FireFox not the actual file.

Comment: @KingMaximo we can't help you if you won't provide more information about the page in question. What you've provided gives no information at all. Copy/pasting from the generated source rather than your source code would be more helpful too so that we can see other potential issues. For instance, if `DEF_ROOT` contains a `"` then you are outputting mangled HTML.

Comment: It's not just one page in question, it is any link, on any page that contains a <% %> in the link.  This could be a blank page with only a link and nothing more. DEF_ROOT contains a URL.

Comment: @KingMaximo: Could you perhaps post your CSS rules for that `.normal_link` class?

Answer (score 0):

Because Internet Explorer is the only browser that supports it.

Comment: The link works in FireFox, it just the CLASS will not work until the link is clicked.

Comment: You said VBScript, which is Client Side.

Comment: Code between <% %> is vbscript it just runs on the server!

Comment: Classic ASP can also use server-side VBS. @KingMaximo That said, IE does support client-side VBS. This is where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: That's what the <% %> implies, that states the code between those symbols should be ran on the server-side.